# SiteMapProvider for MySites' breadcrumb

Tags: 2010, development, navigation, breadcrumb

My question is regarding the `Site Map Provider`.

I have a **breadcrumb** in the mysites and I use **SPContentMapProvider** to build the breadcrumb, but the problem is it always shows `'Home'`, so if I m on my profile page, it shows home, if I'm on the who is who page it still shows Home.

My ideas is to have a correct breadcrumb so it could show My Profile or Who is who in the breadcrumb. What provider should I use?
I tried some but I don't get the correct result, it either it doesn't show anything with the current site map provider, or just shows My Sites and that is it.

Anyone has any idea?

PS I tried **MySiteMapProvider**, but it returns empty breadcrumb.

Comment: http://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/the-breadcrumb-in-sharepoint-2010/ Works like a charm